# Search specific value from field that contains single quote character

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to search a column in PostgreSQL that has values containing single quote characters.
Here's the string I'd like to search and fail to do properly:

`activities,'L','D'`

I've tried using LIKE with both $$ and '' to escape the single quotes but im not able to properly write down the query.

Here is my where clause:

`where  1=1 and table.column LIKE '%activities,''L'',''D''%'`

thank you in advance

Comment: That where clause works properly to find your string, specify better your problem or error message.

Comment: Using dollar-quoted strings, the entire pattern should be enclosed (`LIKE $$%activities,'L','D'%$$`)

Comment: @PepeNO I know it should, but it does not! That is why i am trying to see if there can be any alternatives here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to thank everyone for their input!
It turned out the issue was not withe the SQL code itself, but rather with the fact the text was not consistent within the text column itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes to escape the single quotes, as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE table.column LIKE 'ctivities,''L'',''D''';
```

Yoy can find a working example here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hHCyXADG7dPGgsdf6kVf9d/8